# HtmlWebPackPlugin is unable to resolve fields

Tags: webpack

I've changed my configuration files in order to be able to use `webpack@2.1.0-beta.27`. After having changed some issues according to migration between `webpack@2.1.0-beta.22` and the last one something goes wrong according to `HtmlWebPackPlugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    })
]
```

After having performed `webpack` command it seems that `HtmlWebPackPlugin` is unable to resolve some fields. `index.html` file:

```
Html Webpack Plugin:
<pre>
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

  - index.html:77 
    D:/projects/living/user-platform/project/src/index.html:77:33

  - index.html:94 module.exports
    D:/projects/living/user-platform/project/src/index.html:94:3

  - index.js:255 
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:255:16

  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23

  - promise.js:510 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:510:31

  - promise.js:567 Promise._settlePromise
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:567:18

  - promise.js:604 Promise._settlePromiseCtx
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:604:10

  - async.js:143 Async._drainQueue
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:12

  - async.js:148 Async._drainQueues
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:148:10

  - async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues
    [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:14

</pre>
```

- [src/index.html](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/8a5b2d0892c808e9a31793fbe42dcb0d)
- [webpack.common.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/134e19006a6f8da06bf4123c35d8a8a7)
- [webpack.dev.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/365e8cc433ef629d6246776dce0e3092)
- [webpack.prod.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/919e6228b753cbe67f72edfd613a8c99)